# .env Variables inside the compiled JavaScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, environment-variables, vite

I have a React Webapp where i placed a .env file in the root directory and inside a file i use these env variables. Now when i did `npm run build`, in the compiled js file these env variables are clearly written in the js file.

Why is it like this? This should not be like this, right?

`vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { join } from 'path';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config({ path: join(__dirname, '.env') });

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    react()
  ]
})
```

Example Usage of a env variable in my Project:

```
let exampleKey: string = (import.meta.env.VITE_EXAMPLE_KEY as string)
```

I dont know what to try

Comment: It is correct. There is no way to hide env variables in the client application

Comment: If you mean that you have in .env `VITE_EXAMPLE_KEY=value` and that in js file you have `value` instead of `VITE_EXAMPLE_KEY` that is exactly as it is supposed to be. JS cannot access ENV variables on your machine, so they need to be inserted as they are. You cannot really have client-side secrets.

Comment: That's exactly what it's supposed to be like. Hence the `VITE_` prefix to force you to be explicit, and as [the docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) note: _"Since any variables exposed to your Vite source code will end up in your client bundle, `VITE_*` variables should not contain any sensitive information."_

Comment: The only solution is to place sensitive stuff in a server app, for example using node.js